# What does {% include filename %} and {{ content }} mean inside HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>`enter code here`
{% include head.html %}
<body>
    <div class="container jumbotron">
        <h1 class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane float shadow"></i> Flyaway<a href="">.css</a></h1>
        <p class="lead text-right">~ created by <small><a href="http://takentech.com/about.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i> 進擊的燊</a></small> ~</p>
        <ul class="list-inline text-center">
            <li>
                <iframe class="github-btn" src="https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=lushen&amp;repo=flyaway&amp;type=watch&amp;count=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="100px" height="20px"></iframe>
            </li>
            <li>
                <iframe class="github-btn" src="https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=lushen&amp;repo=flyaway&amp;type=fork&amp;count=true" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="102px" height="20px"></iframe>
            </li>
        </ul>
        {{ content }}
        {% include footer.html %}
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/back-to-top.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prefixfree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shake.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/flyaway.js"></script>
</body>   
</html>
```

This is from an opensource project on Github. I just want to understand this code.

There are `head.html` and `footer.html` files, but when I open the `default.html` file on my computer,the head and footer file do not load on the web page. But on the other hand, when I use the 'check'-button on Chrome to see the source code, the head and footer are actually loaded.

At the same time, I've tried searching the internet to find what `{{}}` and `{% include filename%}` really are, but there seems to be no such a syntax.

Comment: Those are most likely tags to be managed by a JS templating engine (I'm unfamiliar with the syntax, but it should be one of the JS included in the page)

Comment: looks like [liquid templating language](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/)

Answer (score 1):

This is most probably just template file of some templating framework, that code will get replaced with PHP or other server side language code.
For example

```
<?php include 'head.html'; ?>
```

Which will include to this document an actual file in same folder with that name.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Twig PHP template. The documentation is [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html).